# Z Axis Cannot Move

Tags: prusa-i3, z-axis, geeetech

I've got a Geeetech Pro B i3 printer (my first 3d printer) and after I've assembled it I started testing the axis. X and Y work well but Z cannot move.

If I disconnect the couplings the motors move by themselves and they move in the same direction.

[image]

If I help a little bit the motors, by turning with my hand, they move and sometimes move without helping anymore but it stops after a few seconds.

I don't know what do to. I've measured the rest of the setup to make sure there aren't any big differences that could create tension.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Check if your Z-Rods and motors are exactly vertical. If not, adjust as needed.

Check if the brass nuts are perfectly aligned with the rods in the position they are forced in by the screws. Shim to adjust if needed.

If they are ok, then your brass nuts might need a little oiling/grease if they stick to the lead screw.